# Python Tutorial Help NLP customer reviews

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I'm fairly new to Python and am following a tutorial on creating a wordcloud based on a customer reviews file. The tutorial link is https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-bad-customer-reviews-with-nlp-d8b36134dc7e

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import pandas as pd

# read data
reviews_df = pd.read_csv("Hotel_Reviews3.csv")
# append the positive and negative text reviews
reviews_df["review"] = reviews_df["Negative_Review"] + reviews_df["Positive_Review"]

# create the label
reviews_df["is_bad_review"] = reviews_df["Reviewer_Score"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 5 else 0)

# select only relevant columns
reviews_df = reviews_df[["review", "is_bad_review"]]
reviews_df.head()
```

Hotel_Reviews3.csv:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZGxj.png

**ERROR MESSAGE**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Positive_Review'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stecd\Desktop\WorldCloud\wordCloud.py", line 6, in <module>
    reviews_df["review"] = reviews_df["Negative_Review"] + reviews_df["Positive_Review"]
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\stecd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Positive_Review'
>>>
```

Comment: Can you add the whole callstack to that error message?

Comment: Yes. Be advised it is very long. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message i'd guess that `Hotel_Reviews3.csv` may not have a `"Positive_Review"` column. It could be that the corresponding table entry is truncated or has whitespaces so that it does not match `"Positive_Review"`.